# Instance Group won't create an instance with GPU: Not enough resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I'm able to create an instance with NVIDIA-K80 manually, however my instance group shows a warning on the instance:

`Instance 'instance-6lqk' creation failed: The zone 'projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.`

Note: Both are create in the same zone

Comment: Did you try changing the zone?

Comment: Maybe change the cloud provider! I can't change the zone.

Answer (score 2):

(Works for Google)

The error message you received indicated that you did everything right but the zone couldn't fulfill your request. From time to time, this happens for a variety of reasons in a single zone. My suggestion would be to use multiple zones and/or multiple regions so that if this happens to you in one zone, you can simply create capacity in another zone.

Note, a lot of our Preemptible GPU users looking to run large workloads on many GPUs do just this. Ask for quota in many regions and run multi-region instance groups to have the best chance to get access to the most capacity possible.

Answer (score 1):

I created my instance group from an instance templates from the [Google doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus)

Using the same example from the Google Doc below:

```
gcloud beta compute instance-templates create gpu-template \
--machine-type n1-standard-2 \
--boot-disk-size 250GB \
--accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=1 \
--image-family ubuntu-1604-lts --image-project ubuntu-os-cloud \
--maintenance-policy TERMINATE --restart-on-failure \
--metadata startup-script='#!/bin/bash
echo "Checking for CUDA and installing."
# Check for CUDA and try to install.
if ! dpkg-query -W cuda-9-0; then
  curl -O http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
  dpkg -i ./cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
  apt-get update
  apt-get install cuda-9-0 -y
fi'
```

However I found [some](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/e9K3h3fQuJk) recommendations when you are creating a GPU instances. Make sure you have necessary Quotas in the zone, and Michael commented about the GPU restrictions.

hope it can be useful to you.